# Marginal effect for mixed effects models (for python statsmodels)

Tags: mixed-model, python, interpretation, statsmodels, marginal-effect

I have a mixed effects model, developed using python statsmodels, and I want to know the effect of each independent variable on the response variable, assuming all other variables are constant. Based on my research, marginal effect is the way to go. While there is a method in **R** program for getting the marginal effect, it seems that it is not available for python statsmodels.

My question are:

**1.** Is there any way that I can get marginal effects for mixed effects models developed using python statsmodels? (I get the following error when I use `get_margeff()`)
`AttributeError: 'MixedLMResults' object has no attribute 'get_margeff'`

**2.** Is there any alternative for investigating my original question?(finding the effect of variables)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please can you tell us more about your research question ? Also please edit the qusestion to show us the model formula and output